# How to run the functional version of <select from 10#trade>?

Tags: kdb

I want to execute the following in an RDB or any other proc:

`` ?[(10;#;`trade);();0b;()] (1) ``

I have a parser that converts string qsql queries to functional form and then send them from the gw to the correct process to be resolved. All well with more complex queries , but now someone wants to run `10#trade`.

In order for my parser to work I need to convert it to the functional form of `select from 10#trade`. The only problem is that when I do that I get a `Mismatched` error on the process.

I cannot seem to run `(1)` even directly on the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is trying to mix a parse tree with a functional select which is not going to work.

You can limit from within a select/functional-select:

- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/#rank-5

```
parse"select[5] from trade"
?
`trade
()
0b
()
5
?[`trade;();0b;();5]
a
-
1
1
1
1
1
```

- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/parsetrees/
- https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/
- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/

To do exactly what you asked would be:

```
?[eval  (#;5;`trade);();0b;()]
a
-
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: thank you. This is what I was looking for. I completely forgot about ```select[5]from table```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here. Firstly your parse tree of `10#trade` is in the wrong order in the expression labeled (1). It should read `` (#;10;`trade) ``

```
q)value(#;10;`trade)
`trade`trade`trade`trade`trade`trade`trade`trade`trade`trade
q)value(10;#;`trade)
'length
  [0]  value(10;#;`trade)
```

Secondly, as you can see, evaluating that parse tree gives you a list of symbols, which breaks the functional select, since it expects a table or table name as the first parameter.

What you can do is run `eval` on that parse tree inside your functional select, which will give you your result. But this actually does more work than you need, as the result of `eval` is what you're looking for, without running the functional select. But running an `eval` on user supplied code is generally a bad idea, as it's subject to code injection.

```
q)?[eval(#;10;`trade);();0b;()]
```

What might work better for you instead is to consider the 5th parameter of a functional select: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/#rank-5. This behaves just like the `#` operator:

```
q)(10#trade)~select[10]from trade
1b
q)// functional form:
q)(10#trade)~?[`trade;();0b;();10]
1b
```